# State mixtures at beam splitters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, coherent-states

I am currently dealing with beam splitter transformations. As a little exercise, I wanted to calculate what happens if I mix states at a BS with transmission $T$.

I derived a "general formula" if one wants to mix two states with number representations $\hat{\rho}_{A} = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{A}(n,m) |m\rangle\langle n|$ and $\hat{\rho}_{B} = \sum_{m,n} \rho_{B}(m,n) |m\rangle\langle n| $ which seems to be the brute-force approach (brief description in the spoiler, but not too important for my question).

> Denoting the beam splitter transformation by $B$, we obtain the output by $\rho_{out} = B~ (\hat{\rho}_{A} \otimes \hat{\rho}_{B})~B^{\dagger}$. My general approach is then to rewrite each Fock state as $|k\rangle = \frac{(\hat{a_i}^{\dagger})^k}{\sqrt{k!}}$ (where $i = 0$ for the first input and $i=1$ for the second input). Then, I express $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_i$ for $i =0,1$ by the operators corresponding to the output modes of the beam splitter $\hat{a}^{\dagger}_j$ for $j=2,3$ using the beam splitter transformations. After a long and tedious calculation I arrive at an expression in the number basis.

There are also some easier ways to do this for some special states like single photons or two coherent states $|\alpha\rangle_0 |\beta\rangle_1 \rightarrow |\frac{\alpha + i\beta}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle_2 |\frac{\beta + i \alpha}{\sqrt{2}}\rangle_3$ at a 50:50 beam splitter.

After playing around with some easy examples, I arrived at the question what happens if I mix a thermal state $\rho_{th} = \sum_n \frac{\bar{n}^n}{(1+\bar{n})^{n+1}}$ with a coherent state (for example, at a 50:50 BS). Is there any way how I can avoid using my general approach from above? (I hoped to find some easier expression for somehow "basic" states like thermal and coherent states)

Furthermore, I wondered whether there exists any relation or rule what happens if I mix a coherent state with a thermal state $\rho_{th}(\bar{n}_1)$ and then the resulting state with another thermal state $\rho_{th}(\bar{n}_2)$. So, can this be replaced by just one mixture of a coherent state with some thermal state $\rho_{th}(\bar{n}_3)$? If yes, how do I choose corresponding the mean photon number $\bar{n}_3$?

I already tried to answer my questions by inserting the states into my general approach and find some similarities in the results with known states, but I couldn't spot any... Therefore, I would appreciate any input that helps to answer my questions!

Comment: Instead of the number state can’t you proceed by expressing the thermal state as a superposition of coherent states?

Comment: Do you mean: $\rho_{th} = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \int d^2\alpha \int d^2\beta ~ |\beta\rangle\langle \alpha | ~ \langle \beta| \rho_{th} | \alpha\rangle$ and then treating the mixture of the state $| \beta \rangle\langle \alpha|$ with another coherent state?